# Thinking of an example to teach Probability

Tags: probability

Usually, people tend to confuse the interpretation of confidence intervals. The following two statements are said to be quite confusing (even to myself):

- A $95\%$ Confidence Interval means that the population parameter will be contained within this interval with a probability of $0.95$ (incorrect)
- A $95\%$ Confidence Interval means that the Confidence Interval itself has a $0.95$ probability of containing the population parameter (less incorrect)

I was wondering if it is possible to create some example (e.g., an R/Python simulation) which shows that why one of the above statements is more correct than the other.

But is it possible to create an example in which it becomes clear that interpreting a confidence interval as "the probability of the population parameter being contained within this interval" is clearly incorrect or results in a contradiction?

Perhaps someone can think of such an example or provide a link/reference to such an example?

As an example - could someone:

- Simulate some data in Python
- Reputedly take samples from this data and calculate the mean of each sample as well as the $95\%$ confidence interval
- And then show that in general, there is NOT a $0.95$ probability that the population average is contained in within this interval

Thanks!

Comment: Once the interval is created, there is no probability left.  The true value either is or is not in the interval.  The meaning behind the concept is that, $95\%$ of the time, the interval you construct in this manner will in fact contain the true value.  The confusion might be likened to "before you toss a fair die, there is a $\frac 16$ chance that it comes up $6$."  If you toss it and get a $3$, this does not mean that there is a $\frac 16$ chance that $3=6$.

Comment: The population parameter is not a random variable - it has a fixed, although unknown, value. So no probability can be ascribed to it. On the other hand, the confidence interval is variable and depends on the sample.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the language in which your 'correct' and 'incorrect' interpretations are couched. You need instead to stress the process of getting a confidence interval, not the interval which is the outcome of this process. For instance, both of the following statements are correct: "when you follow the process for finding a confidence interval there is a $0.95$ probability that the population parameter will lie in it" and "there is a $0.95$ probability that the population parameter will lie in the interval calculated when you follow the process for finding confidence intervals"; in fact they are identical statements. Both of the following statements, on the other hand, are incorrect: "when you have found a confidence interval there is a $0.95$ probability that the population parameter will lie in it" and "there is a $0.95$ probability that the population parameter lies in the confidence interval you have found"; in fact they are identical statements. So, it isn't the grammatical structure of the sentence that is the error, but the ascription of probability to whether or not one fixed (albeit unknown) number lies between two other numbers that you have already calculated.

To be correct, you need to refer to what could happen when you use some data to calculate a confidence interval - then the probability comes from the fact that you might get samples which are more or less representative of the population and so the CI process may or may not give bounds which include the population parameter. In the same way, it makes sense for me to say that "there is a probability of $0.5$ that, if I have a baby, it will be a boy", but not "there is a probability of $0.5$ that the baby I have just given birth to is a boy".

You won't, therefore, find a simulation of the type you suggest that shows the difference - you will get (approximately) 95% of CI's which contain the population parameter, and 95% of the time the population parameter will lie in the CI: there is no difference between these claims.